# function visibility in the same package

Tags: go

If I understand correctly - all the source files of a package live at the same scope.

I have two files - room.go:

```
package main

func newRoom() *room {
    return &room{
        forward: make(chan []byte),
        join:    make(chan *client),
        leave:   make(chan *client),
        clients: make(map[*client]bool),
        tracer:  trace.Off(),
    }
}
```

main.go:

```
package main

func main() {    
    r := newRoom()
```

When I am compiling the code I get the error:

```
.\main.go:34: undefined: newRoom
```

Why ?

Full code is here https://github.com/matryer/goblueprints/tree/master/chapter1/chat

Comment: what is your compile command and `gopath`

Comment: `go run main.go`

Comment: `echo %GOPATH%` > `C:\Users\demas1252\go`

Comment: try `go run *.go`

Comment: get `GetFileAttributesEx *.go: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: `go run room.go main.go`,  Windows CMD can't expand `*`

Comment: All works fine in this case. But may be there is more correct way to run and build program ?

Comment: it seems not a good practice to split main package into multiple files. package “main” tells the Go compiler that the package should compile as an executable program instead of a shared library

Comment: `go run ...` is _not_ compiling your program. Use `go build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go run *.go` will work in unix like system, and in Windows try to list all files in `main` package